# Change size of draggable element upon start of drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a draggable and droppable layout. I'm creating a draggable object when adding it from a typeahead search selection. However I have some "placement" issues. The size of the draggable object is much larger than the container it should be dropped in. This lead to some dropping issues.

I wan't to resize the element to **half it's current size** upon dragging start. How do I do this? The problem is not present in the fiddle unless the `width` of `.semester`is set to around `30%`.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g2oqp0h/11/)

## EDIT:

After having implemented @user619081 solution I wanted make this happen only if the object was very large. I made a global variable `var tempWidth` and updated the code to the following:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
    if(tempWidth < $(this).width()){
        $(this).addClass("moveable");
    }
    tempWidth = $(this).width();
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).removeClass("moveable");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to hook into the drag start and drag stop events of the draggable widget.

**Read more about them here:**

- Drag start (start) - http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start
- Drag stop (stop) - http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

**Now that you know how to use them, you can do something like this:**

```
$(".courseBox").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  containment: "document",
  cursor: "move",
  start: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.helper).css('width', "50%");
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.helper).css('width', "100%");
  }
});
```

Please note that *ui.helper* holds the reference to the element that you are dragging, which is why you see it in the code.

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4wac9r5/1/) too.

Comment: How would I go about it if I wanted to check what the current size of the element is? And therefore only change it if it is big and not when moving it from the small container to the big one, before dropping it on the big one?

Comment: Your question is really vague, I need some more details about what you'd like to accomplish. The draggable element doesn't know where you are going to move it, you may have three drop zones, each one of them might have different size. There isn't a universal approach where we would know what exact size the dragged element should/should not shrink to. We need to limit the scenario in some way. What you can do is for example only shrink if it's being dragged from the big one to the small one and not shrink it if it's being dragged the opposite way, from the small one to the big one.

Comment: What you're describing is exactly what I need. I will have a total of 4 small `droppable zones` and only 1 big one. I only want to resize it if moving from the big one to a smaller one. 

I did manage to get this working with @user619081's approach, as seen in my **EDIT**, but your approach above seems more "right".

Comment: Careful with the more "right" approaches, because it's a slippery slope. My approach on what you describe would probably be to semantically split the logic with some custom classes if the example is isolated. I would add a class, say, "large-drop" to the big drop zone and use it as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/y461ru3c/ - does that work for you? (saw I had an error, so I reposted my comment)

Answer (score 2):

You should look into ondragstart and ondragstop events. Look into ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer if you need to pass some info about original state of DOM element, such as original width or something else.

```
$(".courseBox").on('dragstart', function(ev) {
  $(this).css('width', '50%');
});

$(".courseBox").on('dragstop', function(ev) {
  $(this).css('width', '100%');
});
```

Comment: How would I check what the original size of the element is? I tried looking on google, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have updated your fiddle just check it.
It is working with targeted width size
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8g2oqp0h/37/

Comment: That's cool. I don't know why I didn't think of this myself. I did however notice it only working the first time I would drag it down. I didn't work when dragging it back and forth.. Otherwise I would tag your answer as the right answer,

Comment: At least this was how it worked on the fiddle. After implementing it myself it works fine